# Как из строки получить нужный текст

Tags: python, строки, парсер

```
def get_ticker(coin1="btc", coin2="usd"):
     response = requests.get(url=f"https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/{coin1}_{coin2}?ignore_invalid=1")
     return response.text
```

получаю такую строку:

```
{
    "btc_usd": 
    {
        "high":45585.40005,
        "low":39332.5,
        "avg":42458.950025,
        "vol":175485.15417185,
        "vol_cur":4.13745935,
        "last":45209.6,
        "buy":44835.00271004,
        "sell":45209.69981000,
        "updated":1646134633
    }
}
```

И из строки нужно получить только: `"avg":42458.950025`

Comment: А что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Хотя зря я отформатировал... Но в общем возьмите `response.json()` и там будет вот такой словарь, как я наформатировал. Из него то сможете нужное достать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from json import loads

resp = get_ticker()
as_dict = loads(resp)
avg = as_dict['btc_usd']['avg']
```

Comment: зачем это. когда можно `response.json()` как написали в комментариях

Comment: это упрощает код но не решает проблему

Comment: если люди не умеют работать со словарями, зачем начинать писать ботов и использовать какие-то библиотеки? не зная основы...